# How to properly store event.duration field in Elastic?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, logback

I have a Java service that writes logs in JSON format, they are then picked up by filebeat and sent to Elastic. I would like to be able to set one of the ECS fields (`event.duration`) described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-event.html#field-event-duration)
I set up a `net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` encoder, and I set the `event.duration` field in MDC before calling logging method. The output looks like this:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-12-07T10:41:59.589+01:00",
  "message": "message",
  "event.duration": "5606000000",
  "service": {
    "name": "logging.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED",
    "type": "java"
  },
  "log": {
    "logger": "com.demo.Demo",
    "level": "WARN"
  },
  "process": {
    "thread": {
      "name": "main"
    }
  },
  "error": {}
}
```

However, in Kibana I see `event.duration` as a JSON inside the `flat` field:

```
flat
{
  "event.duration": "10051000000"
}
```

How can I make it on the same level as other ECS fields like `event.name`?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an ingest pipeline using the [`dot_expander` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dot-expand-processor.html) in order to transform your dotted field into an object:

```
PUT _inest/pipeline/de-dot
{
  "processors" : [
    {
      "dot_expander": {
        "field": "event.duration"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to make sure that your indexing process references this pipeline, i.e. `...?pipeline=de-dot`